# Select an tag with $(this)

Tags: jquery, html, tags

I have the following code

```
$("#accordian h3").click(function(){            
        $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp();            
            if(!$(this).next().is(":visible"))
            {
                $(this).next().slideDown(); 
                $(this).addClass('fa-chevron-up');
            }
        })
    })
```

And in this case corresponds to an header tag `(h3)` that in the text has another tag `(<i>)` that needs to be changed... the problem here is that I'm not being able to get the I tag.

I've tryed `$(this + ' i')`.... but no luck. This is the error logged to the console

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLHeadingElement] i
```

Comment: Off topic: "accordion"

Comment: I don't think that error is from this code

Comment: I'm not clear on the problem. It would help to see the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve. From what I understood, trying `$(this).find("i")` may solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `i` tag is within each of the `h3`'s, correct? If so:

```
$('i', this)...
```

This makes use of [context](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1) when making a Jquery selector.